# Creating a meta-epic which works like combineEpics but selects one epic based on namespace

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming, reactive

I'm trying to *namespace* my epics. I basically want to combine my epics, but the epic used should depend on what namespace is set in my state.
I've gotten here so far:

```
const epics = {
  'ns1': nameSpace1Epic,
  'ns2': nameSpace2Epic,
  'default': (action$, store) => {
    return Observable.of({type: 'NOP'})
  }
}
const superEpic = (action$, store) => {
  const { namespace } = store.getState()
  const epic = epics[namespace]
  const resultAction$ = epic(action$, store)
  return resultAction$
}
```

This works for the first action, it successfully switches to the correct namespace.
However, when the second action comes in, it's still stuck at the first chosen namespace.
No action goes through the superepic, it goes directly to the first epic.

I've been reading the Rx-documentation and experimenting with different types of operators, without any luck.
Does someone have a clue what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to my problem. `superEpic` should be a stream which directs actions (one at a time) to the namespaced streams, what it does now is simply replace itself by another stream. `flatMap` to the rescue:

```
const superEpic = (action$, store) => 
  action$.flatMap(action => {
    const { namespace } = store.getState()
    const epic = epics[namespace]
    return epic(Observable.of(action), store)
  })
```

If you want to use the `ofType` operator in your action streams, make sure to import `ActionsObservable` from `redux-observable/lib/ActionsObservable`
Like this:

`import { ActionsObservable } from 'redux-observable/lib/ActionsObservable'`